# How to connect this seemingly 10 pin fan connector to my 4 pin CPU fan header on my motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I want to connect the following 10 pin fan connector on a fan array in the front of my 1u server case to my motherboard. I have not found a way to do so and from searching online there are no 10 pin fan connectors

[image]

Comment: @Moab Whoops. Corrected that there. Just plugging in the Molex connector doesn't seem to do much either.

Comment: Make and model of Server or motherboard

Comment: https://www.servercase.co.uk/shop/server-cases/rackmount/1u-chassis/1u-server-case-w-4x-35-hot-swappable-sata-drive-bays-sc-1404/ and PSU https://www.servercase.co.uk/shop/server-cases/power-supplies/1u-power-supplies/single-1u-500w-80-plus-psu-sc-sg1u500/

Comment: Motherboard Asus Prime Z490